# How to shift one equation only towards the left margin

Tags: equations, margins, amsmath, horizontal-alignment

- I have an equation extending into the
  right margin and off the page.
- I have many equations.  For this
  equation only, I would like to shift
- it to the left.

  MWE below.

  ```
  \documentclass[twoside]{book}                           
  \usepackage{amsmath}                                      
       \begin{document}
          \begin{equation}
                  \text{Some big equation}
          \end{equation}
  \end{document}
  ```

---

Here is an example of an equation I wish to shift left horizontally as it is too far to the right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}                      

        \newcommand{\MyLeftRoundBracket}{(}                                                                         
        \newcommand{\MyRightRoundBracket}{)}                                                                        
        \newcommand{\MyLeftSquareBracket}{[}                                                                        
        \newcommand{\MyRightSquareBracket}{]} 

        \usepackage{amsmath}                                      

     \begin{document}

                \begin{align}\label{eq:CIR_Expected_Return_Variance_Spread}
     ^{Spread}_{CIR}\sigma^2(X^L,X^U,c) &= -{(c-X^L+X^U)^2 \over {_{CIR}\theta_1}^2} {1 \over \Bigg \MyLeftSquareBracket \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2
   {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-}  \cdots  \notag \\
&\qquad {1 \over 
        \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) -\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) + }  \cdots  \notag        \\
   & \qquad\qquad {1 \over \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}, \frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) \Bigg \MyRightSquareBracket^3 } 
\times      \notag  \\
&\qquad \Bigg [ \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}  {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2-\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2 + \notag \\
&\qquad   \frac{\partial \Phi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-\frac{\partial \Phi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)+ \notag \\
&\qquad  \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2
   {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2-\frac{\partial \Psi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-         \notag \\
&\qquad   \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2+\frac{\partial \Psi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
   {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)\Bigg ]
   \end{align}              

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you include the actual equation? Is breaking the equation up in multiple lines an option?

Comment: @Michel,all I want to do do is shift anything wrapped in the equation command to the left. This should be a common requirement.  I have 100's of equations but 5 or so overlap off the page of my PhD thesis. I want to shift those equations only to the left. I gave ab example of an equation as requested.NOTE: There are other formatting issues going on,so the example is not off the page but does extend far right.  I added the example to a separate section as not to clutter the real question.  Which is just to shift anything in the equation or dmath or align command to the right.

Comment: Is not the same question ! I modified my answer

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to provide more details. The answer section is for solutions only. I moved your answer to the question to keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}                           
\usepackage{amsmath}                                      
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \hspace*{-10cm}   \text{Some big equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
       \text{Some big equation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}]
```

[image]

With `align`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}                      

        \newcommand{\MyLeftRoundBracket}{(}                                                                         
        \newcommand{\MyRightRoundBracket}{)}                                                                        
        \newcommand{\MyLeftSquareBracket}{[}                                                                        
        \newcommand{\MyRightSquareBracket}{]} 

        \usepackage{amsmath}                                      

     \begin{document}

  \hspace*{-3cm}\vbox{\begin{align}\label{eq:CIR_Expected_Return_Variance_Spread}
       ^{Spread}_{CIR}\sigma^2(X^L,X^U,c) &= -{(c-X^L+X^U)^2 \over {_{CIR}\theta_1}^2} {1 \over \Bigg \MyLeftSquareBracket \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2
     {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-}  \cdots  \notag \\
  &\qquad {1 \over 
          \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) -\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) + }  \cdots  \notag        \\
     & \qquad\qquad {1 \over \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}, \frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big) \Bigg \MyRightSquareBracket^3 } 
  \times      \notag  \\
  &\qquad \Bigg [ \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}  {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2-\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2 + \notag \\
  &\qquad   \frac{\partial \Phi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-\frac{\partial \Phi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)+ \notag \\
  &\qquad  \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2
     {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2-\frac{\partial \Psi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     X^L}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)-         \notag \\
  &\qquad   \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial a}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)^2+\frac{\partial \Psi^2}{\partial a^2}\Big(0,\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1}
     {_{CIR}\theta_2}}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}},\frac{2 {_{CIR}\theta_1} X^U}{{_{CIR}\theta_3}}\Big)\Bigg ]
     \end{align}  }            

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the equation is simply too wide, it's wider than the textblock. A better solution would be to change the equation, a break after the equals sign could be an option.

Comment: @Michel I agree with you but the OP wants to shift left horizontally the equation so ...