# Shift two equations to the left

Tags: equations, formatting

I saw similar posts and I tried their solutions, but it still does not work as I am using `align` instead of `equation` found in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14548/how-to-shift-one-equation-only-towards-the-left-margin)

**Question**:

Given I have the following,

```
\begin{align}
x\sim \left(1-\varepsilon \right) \mathcal{N} \left(\mu _0,\Sigma _W \right) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\epsilon _h\mathcal{N} \left( \mu _h,\Sigma _W \right)}\\
\end{align}
```

How do I shift the equation to the left given I have the IEEETran document (two columns)?

**Edit**: I solved it by adding `\hspace{-1.0cm}` in front of every equation inside `align` and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the  `nccmath` package, which defines a `fleqn` environment, which works somewhat like `subequations`. Note that this environment accepts an optional argument  to set the value of `\displayindent` (0pt by default):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
 & X_{n+1} = [aX_{n} + c] \mod m \\
 &\rlap{\upshape \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\enspace}l}
 $ m $, & the Modulus ($ m > 0 $), \\
 $a$, & the Multiplier ($ 0 < a \leq m $), \\
 $c$, & the increment ($ 0 \leq c < m $), \\
 $X_n$, & the starting value
\end{tabular}}\notag
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

$\begin{aligned}
   f_{s_{i}} &=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}∑_{j=1}ⁿg(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
    g(d_{ij}) &=
  \begin{cases}
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    \exp\Bigl(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\Bigr) & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$
\bigskip

$\begin{aligned}
   &f_{s_{i}} =-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}∑_{j=1}ⁿg(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   &g(d_{ij}) =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
    \exp\
    \bigl(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\bigr) & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure but it renders error,

$\begin{aligned}
x\sim \left(1-\varepsilon \right) \mathcal{N} \left(\mu _0,\Sigma _W \right) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\epsilon _h\mathcal{N} \left( \mu _h,\Sigma _W \right)}\\

\end{aligned}$

Comment: I also tried this one and it rendered errors although I added your packages,

\lipsum[3]
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}
    x\sim (1-\varepsilon) \mathcal{N} (\mu _0,\Sigma _W ) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\epsilon _h\mathcal{N} ( \mu _h,\Sigma _W )}\\
 &\rlap{\upshape \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\enspace}l}

\end{tabular}}\notag
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I tried `\hspace{-1.0cm}` solved my problem.

Comment: @Abraheem: What errors did you have, both with `$\begin{aligned}…$` and with `fleqn`?